# The serialized object result of my unit client is different from that of the c# console server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

same class for serialize:

```
using System;
[Serializable]
class Class2
{
    public int a;
}
```

same serialize function:

```
        public static byte[] Serialize(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || !obj.GetType().IsSerializable)
            {
                return null;
            }

            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
                byte[] data = stream.ToArray();
                return data;
            }
        }
```

sever:

```
Class2 c = new Class2();
c.a = 1 ;
byte[] data = NetworkUtils.Serialize(c);
Console.WriteLine( BitConverter.ToString(data));
```

unity client:

```
Class2 c = new Class2();
c.a = 1;
byte[] data = NetworkUtils.Serialize(c);
Debug.Log("测试序列化 " + BitConverter.ToString(data));
```

is this problem about .net edition?
unity is standard2,server is core3.1

unity result:
00-01-00-00-00-FF-FF-FF-FF-01-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-0C-02-00-00-00-46-41-73-73-65-6D-62-6C-79-2D-43-53-68-61-72-70-2C-20-56-65-72-73-69-6F-6E-3D-30-2E-30-2E-30-2E-30-2C-20-43-75-6C-74-75-72-65-3D-6E-65-75-74-72-61-6C-2C-20-50-75-62-6C-69-63-4B-65-79-54-6F-6B-65-6E-3D-6E-75-6C-6C-05-01-00-00-00-06-43-6C-61-73-73-32-01-00-00-00-01-61-00-08-02-00-00-00-01-00-00-00-0B
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)

server result:
00-01-00-00-00-FF-FF-FF-FF-01-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-0C-02-00-00-00-3B-47-61-6D-65-2C-20-56-65-72-73-69-6F-6E-3D-31-2E-30-2E-30-2E-30-2C-20-43-75-6C-74-75-72-65-3D-6E-65-75-74-72-61-6C-2C-20-50-75-62-6C-69-63-4B-65-79-54-6F-6B-65-6E-3D-6E-75-6C-6C-05-01-00-00-00-06-43-6C-61-73-73-32-01-00-00-00-01-61-00-08-02-00-00-00-01-00-00-00-0B

PS:If I make the class into a DLL file and import it, this problem will not appear,But this method is too troublesome

Comment: @derHugo  I added the results above and i will learn JSON to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compare the strings what you get is on your server

```
FAssembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Class2 a
```

And in Unity

```
Game, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Class2 a
```

(I left out the not printable Chars) The difference is the [Assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/assembly/) name. In Unity it is `Game`, on your server it is `FAssembly`.

---

In general as said [**STOP using BinaryFormatter at all!**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)!

Despite the security concerns it is also a huge waste of bandwidth!

In Unity you send `111` and on the server even `122` bytes!

Your class has a single `int` field which only requires `4` bytes of data!

As said I would rather implement

```
[Serializable]
class Class2
{
    public int a;

    public byte[] ToBytes()
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
    }

    public Class2(){}

    public Class2(byte[] bytes)
    {
        a = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much.This means that the Assembly name is included in the serialization result, so serialization results is different?now i want to use newtonsoft,Is this a good choice?

Comment: At the bottom I showed you what I would use. For a single int field you need no more then 4 bytes .. even JSON would say e.g.  `{"a":123}`  which is still some overhead

Comment: I see. Thank you again